# Are HTTP 1.1 methods like PUT, DELETE, etc. were added explicitly to support REST?

Tags: rest, http

It is often said that you should use PUT, DELETE, and other methods of HTTP 1.1 to provide a RESTful API. The purpose is to make URI to reference a resource (representation) and the method designate the action to be done. I see that HTTP 1.1 was released in 1997 and Fielding's PhD paper introducing REST took place in 2000. So, why those methods, besides GET and POST, were really added into the HTML 1.1 spec in the first place?

It would be great to have a reference on an article of something like that explaining why HTTP 1.1 method set was expanded since HTTP 1.0 without references to REST that appeared 3 years later.

Comment: REST doesn't really exist, it just means "not using any other more complex API framework"

Comment: Yes, I understand, but Roy Fielding was involved in HTTP and URI specification and his *archytectical style* called REST. I may suspect that he somehow influenced HTTP 1.1 to have PUT and DELETE and officially formulated the ideas later in his PhD. But otherwise, HTTP was a means to transfer HTML pages in the first place, why add PUT and DELETE methods then? That is what really makes me curious.

Comment: I mean, do not you see that PUT and DELETE methods are somewhat foreign to the idea of just *transferring hypertext over the internet* rather than being a means to *edit* hypertext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP/1.0 had `PUT` and `DELETE` and predated the dissertation by several years.

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt

Document is from 1996.

Aside from that, the REST dissertation was meant to describe the architecture of the web itself, not JSON apis (you didn't explicitly mention this but it's a common misconception). HTTP and HTML are an implementation of the REST architecture, even though REST was described after the first few versions HTML and HTTP.

So if you're curious if HTTP/1.1 sometimes describes things in a way that matches the REST dissertation, I think that kinda goes without saying. They had the same author, they were written around the same time and the one documentation describes the REST architecture, and the other is (part of) an implementation of the REST architecture.